# Mozilla Thunderbird detecta el correo de SOes como posible scam

Tags: discusión, estado-completado

Estaba mirando el correo y veo que me llega un mensaje de *@Trauma* por medio de las notificaciones del chat que se envìan por correo.

Noté un cuadro rojo que decía que el correo era *probablemente un Scam*.

Solo ocurre con los mensajes *inbox* del chat, con demás los correos de la red *StackExchange* no ocurre.

¿Será que *Mozilla* desconfía de ese tipo de mensajes?

[image: Mensaje de Trauma]

Comment: A mí gmail también lleva marcándome el boletín semanal como spam desde hace semanas. Estoy suscrito a unos cuantos y casi todos me los marca así semana a semana

Comment: Reportaré esto para que se pueda agregar a la lista de bugs. ¡Gracias por compartir!

Comment: Esto es un bug que no podemos solucionar por nuestra parte, les comparto una solución en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este [bug](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) ocurre cuando uno usa el cliente de Thunderbird en inglés con correo que no esta en el mismo idioma.  Esta combinación ha resultado en varias alertas sin importar la plataforma.  Aquí una sugerencia para ayudar con este problema:

[Detección de mensajes fraudulentos en Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/es/kb/deteccin-de-mensajes-fraudulentos-en-thunderbird)

Comment: Bien, actualmente el language pack en español no es compatible con mi versión, quizás también haya un problema en la arquitectura, ahora actualicé Thunderbird y no me aparece más el mensaje, cosas raras que pasan.